# How to get the list of all announced bonjour services on all available domains?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch, macos, bonjour

It's not the problem to look in all domains, but I can't find the right way to look for any service on the network.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Old thread but there is a way to find the local services [Discovering all advertised Bonjour service types](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/qa/qa1337/_index.html). You will need to do some manipulation of the results to get the types in the correct format. This works on Mac & iPhone although no services are discovered if I haven't got a Wifi connection on iPhone.

```
    NSNetServiceBrowser* domainBrowser = [[NSNetServiceBrowser alloc] init];
    domainBrowser.delegate = self;
    [domainBrowser searchForServicesOfType:@"_services._dns-sd._udp."
                              inDomain:@"local."];
```

Comment: Works on macOS 13.

Answer (score 4):

To my knowledge, there's not a function that will search for all available services.  The reason is probably because an application publishing a service can define its own service type.

If you are only looking for services of common types (HTTP, printer, etc) you can easily create a loop to call [`-[instanceOfNSNetServiceBrowser searchForServicesOfType:inDomain:]`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNetServiceBrowser_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNetServiceBrowser/searchForServicesOfType:inDomain:) with all the types you want, in all the domains you previously discovered.

The [developer docs guide section on setting up a NSNetService](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Networking/Conceptual/NSNetServiceProgGuide/Articles/PublishingServices.html) can also be of aid.

Comment: Yeah, seems that that is the only way