# Detection of wifi devices on mac using bonjour

Tags: macos, bonjour

I needed some help reagarding, how to detect all wifi devices connected using bonjour, and to display those devices on mac application. A sample application would be lot helpful. If not, an direction in which i can proceed to accomplish my task.

Answer (score 1):

A good place to start would be to check that you can see the devices using Bonjour Browser from http://www.tildesoft.com. If they're not advertising a service then you're not going to see anything.

There is a basic description on how to discover Bonjour services here:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Networking/Conceptual/dns_discovery_api/Articles/browse.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002486-SW1

To discover all services look at this answer here:
[How to get the list of all announced bonjour services on all available domains?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1587264/how-to-get-the-list-of-all-announced-bonjour-services-on-all-available-domains)